# create a excel file and I want to send that as an attachment to email without saving file in local system

Tags: java, spring, io

i want to add excel file and fetch data from the db and save data to excel file and send this excel file as an attachment to mail and that excel file should not save into local disk

Comment: i need to send excel file to mail without saving into computer and i need some guidance

Comment: You can save the excel file into ByteArrayOutputStream and store the data into byte[]. Then send it out as attachment.